# Remove "Elastic" effect in Popmotion Pose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popmotion

I try to do a simple `x` and `opacity` transition with Popmotion Pose for React, but i dont know how to remove the default "elastic" (bounce?) effect.

```
    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      delay: 200,
      transition: {
        default: { type: 'tween', ease: 'easeOut', duration: 200 }
      }
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: xExit,
      transition: {
        x: ({ from, to }) => ({
          type: 'keyframes',
          values: [from, -xExit, to],
          times: [0, 0.99, 1]
        }),
        opacity: ({ from, to }) => ({
          type: 'keyframes',
          values: [from, 0, to],
          times: [0, 0.99, 1]
        }),
        default: { duration: 200 }
      }
    }
```

Did you guys know how to remove it ?

Comment: please tell  library name?

Comment: Yes, just added (Popmotion Pose)